# How is an arc described in the DXF format if it is tilted out of the X-Y plane?

Tags: svg, cad, dxf

I am trying to make sense of the DXF CAD file format.

I have drawn an arc in my (intellicad) CAD software, centre at (5,5,5), radius of 300, start angle 40 degrees and end angle 110. I have then rotated the arc by 5 degrees in the Y-Z plane. I am doing this because I want to see what effect the 210, 220 and 230 group codes (which define the extrusion direction) have.

I am expecting to see this:

```
  0
ARC
 10
5.0
 20
5.0
 30
5.0
 40
300.0
210
0.0
220
0.08715574274765817
230
0.9961946980917455
 50
220.0
 51
290.0
```

Instead I see this:

```
  0
ARC
 10
-5.0
 20
-4.545194776720437
 30
5.416752204197018
 40
300.0
210
0.0
220
0.08715574274765817
230
0.9961946980917455
 50
220.0
 51
290.0
```

Why is the centre of the arc not on (5,5,5)?

I'm trying to parse DXF files in C++ and write it as an SVG, but the values I'm getting won't give me a true depiction.

How does the value of (5.0,5.0,5.0) get changed to (-5.0,-4.545194776720437,5.416752204197018)? Does anyone know?

I'm not sure that anyone can answer this for me, but I have seen questions on the DXF format answered here, so I'm hoping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a DXF expert. But..

If you rotate something at (5,5) around the origin by 5 degrees, you get:

```
5 * sin(5deg) - 5 * cos(5deg) = -4.54519
5 * cos(5deg) + 5 * sin(5deg) = 5.41675
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

function[]=arc_2d_dxf(fid,LAYER,X,Y,RADIUS,GRAD_START,GRAD_FINISH,COLOR)

```
   fprintf(fid,'ARC\n');
   fprintf(fid,'8\n');
   fprintf(fid,'%s\n',LAYER);%LAYER
   fprintf(fid,'10\n');  % x coord code
   fprintf(fid,'%.4f\n',X);
   fprintf(fid,'20\n');  % y coord code
   fprintf(fid,'%.4f\n',Y);
   fprintf(fid,'40\n');  % y coord code
   fprintf(fid,'%.4f\n',RADIUS);% RADIUS
   fprintf(fid,'50\n');  % GRAD START
   fprintf(fid,'%.4f\n',GRAD START);% GRAD
   fprintf(fid,'51\n');  % GRAD FINISH
   fprintf(fid,'%.4f\n',GRAD FINISH);% GRAD
   fprintf(fid,'62\n');  % font code
   fprintf(fid,'%d\n',COLOR); %COLOR,1 RED,2 YELLOW ,3 GREEN, ...   
   fprintf(fid,'0\n');
```